# Word for small chat about the speakers well being

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a word or expression for a **small chat that is about how people are**? For having a bit of context, two characters, who meet up almost on a daily basis, ask each other how they are, before talking about more important subjects. I tried to search for a definite answer, but I haven't found anything suitable. As far as I know, *small talk* might be used, but that includes more subjects, like weather, work and what not. The other one could be stating that they simply had a *chat*, but that could be again about almost any subject. *Catching up* would be the most appropriate one I could think of, but that for me seems as if there should me way more time between the two talking to each other than just a few days. For me catching up has always been associated with long time no see type of conversations. The sentence I want the word to use in is:

- **After a small chat about their well-being and James’s shopping list they made their way to the supermarket.**

Comment: I don’t think there’s one specific to *well-being*. You didn’t ask, but I doubt there’s one specific to shopping lists either. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might be right. But just to clarify, I am not looking for a synonym for _well being_ but for a word or expression for  
 _chatting about how the persons involved in the conversation are_.

Comment: They exchanged pleasantries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you're looking for is [**pleasantries**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleasantries):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **3** : a polite social remark
>   // exchanged *pleasantries*

---

There is also *gossip*, but it's something more intentional and focused than just chatting about the weather or traffic.

So:

> After exchanging *pleasantries* about their well-being and James’s shopping list they made their way to the supermarket.

Answer (score 1):

For me, you have almost said it yourself: "small talk".

This is conversation between people which is will never offend; "How are you?", "Did you find us OK?", "How was the traffic?".

It often precedes a meeting or even something like a Doctor's appointment, or can be the entire conversation between people who are forced together, maybe in the Doctor's waiting room.